# Flow to send automatic reply based on conditions

Tags: sharepoint, automation, outlook, office365, power-automate

I am trying to create a flow in PowerAutomate which should look like this:

1. New email arrives in Shared Mailbox
2. Gets filtered based on these conditions:

- if the domain name ends on xx.com then send automatic reply
- if the person's email address is listed on the SharePoint list (same domain), then don't send automatic reply

My sharepoint list is simple, just two columns - Title and Email

I can't figure it out how to filter it from SharePoint list.

[image]

I have tried using Get Items from SharePoint, then use Filter to filter it out, but can't figure it.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: @Skin https://prnt.sc/RxCitcQhuPdZ

I am no expert, just started with this few days ago.

Comment: You mentioned a filter, I can’t see that there though. Did you have a crack at using one?

Comment: I used Filter Query in Get Items (SharePoint): Email eq '@{triggerBody()?['From']}

Comment: What type of column is the Email column in your list? Is it single line of text or is it a person or group type of field? Also be aware that string comparisons in Power Automate are case sensitive. Are the values of Email and From exactly the same in your test? You might need to use the toLower function in an expression to turn both string values to lowercase.